# Perpendicular distance from a 3D point to a vector in spherical polar coordinates.

Tags: polar-coordinates

I have a point $(r, \theta, \phi)$ and a direction vector with angles $(\theta', \phi')$. What would be the method to calculate the shortest distance from the point to the vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Euclidean distance is
$$
d = 
\sqrt{(r \sin \theta \cos \phi - \sin \theta' \cos \phi')^2 +
(r \sin \theta \sin \phi - \sin \theta' \sin \phi')^2 +
(r \cos \theta - \cos \theta')^2}
$$
As the point and vector are given, there is only this distance, which is the shortest by lack of alternatives.